# How can I run the python script which contain libraries from php hosted on heroku?

Tags: php, python, opencv, heroku

I am all new to Heroku and I wanted to call the python script which contains libraries like numpy and opencv. They execute on localhost from PHP when I call them using shell_exec() or exec() function. But in Heroku, only simple python script which does not contain any library imported are executing. Whenever the libraries are imported it fails. I have set the buildpack as PHP and python.

I want that python script to be executed from PHP please help me with it!.
I have searched a lot but methods are not working. They are working fine on local host.

In alternative if there is a way in which I can host the application apart from heroku where both the php and python script can be executed let me know about that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create requirements.txt  by using cmd `pip freeze > requirements.txt`  in the desired folder it will define all the required libraries or do it manually in the following format:-

```
Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And then deploy your app.

Let me know if it worked.